# Hamiltonian Simulation in Qiskit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, hamiltonian, quantum-computer, software

I would like to simulate the time evolution of a quantum system Qiskit. Qiskit, however, only supports Hamiltonians that are a sum of hermitian matrices and that can be expanded into tensor products of Pauli-operators. I have the following Hamiltonian:
$$H = q(r_\textit{ref}-r) \sum_{k=0}^N A_k \cos(kt-\varphi_k).$$
The kinetic energy is $0$ and the Hamiltonian is simply the potential energy that the system (with charge total $q$) feels due to an external electric field in the form of a Fourier series. Is this a Hamiltonian of the kind described above? I.e. can I decompose it into Pauli-operators?

Here is the question on stack exchange that I reviewed: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4017/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly are $t$, $\varphi_k$, etc. here?

Comment: $t,A_k,k,\varphi_k,r,r_\text{ref}$ are time, Amplitudes of the siniusoids, angular frequencies of the siniusoids, phases of the siniusoids, position and reference position respectively.

Comment: @BySymmetry See above comment

Comment: OK, so if I understand your setup correctly, the only operator in your Hamiltonian is the position $r$. This cannot (simply, with making various approximations) be written in terms of Pauli matrices. On the other hand, without a kinetic term, the Hamiltonain is already diagonal in the position basis, so you should be able to calculate the dynamics with a pen and paper.

Comment: @BySymmetry Thank you for your commet. I guess so, although the position $r$ is not really relevant to my system and should stay constant, my interest is in the time-dependance of the electric field, which causes varying potential energy. Can you explain what you mean by diagonal in the position basis? And why is this the case when there is no kinetic energy term?

Comment: If $r$ is staying constant, what exactly are the degrees of freedom in your system? What is allowed to change? What is the physical system you are considering exactly?

Comment: @BySymmetry The state of the system in general. I would like this state to represent a qubit. This could be the polarization or spin of the system.

Comment: ok... how does the energy of the system depend on its state? I suggest you read the first chapter or 2 of a quantum mechanics textbook. I think you need to get a clearer picture of the role played by the Hamiltonian of a quantum system

Comment: @BySymmetry I don’t think it does. In this case, the external electric field influences the state of the system. Right?

Comment: This just does not seem to have the right mathematical structure to be a quantum Hamiltonian (or a classical one for that matter). I suggest you do some reading and come back when you have a clearer pickture of how to formulate your problem

Answer (score 0):

I've made some videos on time evolution in Qiskit in my [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqkyCsvQYy8nuO86yD3IBHQ). Hopefully it can help you. However, there I assume that you already have your Hamiltonian operator written in terms of the Pauli basis $\{ I,X,Y,Z \}$. I guess your Hamiltonian is not of this kind, unless your provide an explicit expression for $q(\mathbf r_{ref} - r)$. If your system consists in a harmonic oscillator, for example, you can write $\mathbf r$ in terms of ladder operators $a$ and $a^\dagger$, which can be expanded in terms of the Pauli basis (check out my videos).

Nevertheless, knowing the following fact may help you: its not hard to show that *any* 2x2 matrix $A$ can be written as a linear combination of the Pauli basis: just write $A = \alpha I + \beta X + \gamma Y + \delta Z$ and verify that the linear system has always a nontrivial solution. Likewise, any 4x4, 8x8, etc., operator can be written in terms of tensor products of this same basis.

Perhaps if you furnish more detail about your Hamiltonian, we can go further.